# Is it correct to say " dans un mois et quelque" ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

I'm confused about whether to say "dans un mois et quelques jours" or just "dans un mois et quelque". Also, how do we say "one and a half months"?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It is certainly correct and idiomatic to say it.

> *Dans un mois et quelque(s).*

means, "in one month plus some (days)" if you use the plural (*Dans un mois et quelques jours*) or plus some unspecified amount of time if you use the singular (*Dans un mois et "quelque temps"*).

You might also use the idiom:

> *Dans un mois et des poussières.*

to state a very small amount of time need to be added to that duration, and for a larger amount, that might be:

> *Dans un mois et des brouettes.*

For *in one and a half month*, you would say:

> *Dans un mois et demi.*  (one month and a half)

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion